# How do I run arbitrary SQL against Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails, I want to show on a page how many new "users" are created each "day".

In regular SQL, I would do something like:

```
SELECT 
DATE(created_at) as day,
COUNT(1) as new_user_count
FROM users
WHERE created_at > '2014-01-01 01:01:01'
GROUP BY day
```

How can I execute this against my `Users` table in Rails? Again, I need to show this on a page, so I'm not looking for instructions on the PG GUI.

For specifics, I'm using Heroku and Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
sql = "SELECT DATE(created_at) as day, COUNT(1) as new_user_count " \
      "FROM users WHERE created_at > '2014-01-01 01:01:01' " \
      "GROUP BY day"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Comment: are you forgetting to close the string at the end? *QUERY>>

Comment: @DonnyP Nope. See http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "users" - looks like we need spaces after each row too :)

Comment: @DonnyP Updated. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from a raw SQL solution, you might consider creating a view:

```
create view daily_user_counts as
SELECT 
  DATE(created_at) as day,
  COUNT(*) as new_user_count
FROM users
WHERE created_at > '2014-01-01 01:01:01'
GROUP BY day;
```

... and creating a read-only model for it:

```
class DailyUserCount < ActiveRecord::Base

  def readonly?
    true
  end

end
```

Then:

```
DailyUserCount.where("day > ? ", from).order(:day)
```